# JavaScript load image file from a different directory

Tags: javascript, path, directory

In JavaScript I want to load an image file from a different directory. My file structure is as such:

```
Project/js/script.js
Project/img/1.png
```

In `script.js` I want the following:

```
document.getElementById("image").src = "Project/img/1.png";
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: What is the path of your main HTML file?  That is what establishes the base path by which relative paths are evaluated.

Comment: `Project/index.html`

Comment: Try document.getElementById("image").src = "/img/1.png";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML file establishes the base path by which other relative paths are evaluated.  So, if your HTML file path is `"http://example.com/something/Project/index.html"`, then the Project directory is already the default location so you can access other things relative to the `Project` directory like this:

```
js/script.js
img/1.png
```

Any relative path that does not start with a domain or with `/` will have `http://example.com/something/Project/` prepended to it.

Answer (score 1):

The browser doesn't ever know what ***root*** folder the files are in - it only knows what it sees from the URL.  It seems like your project's root is in the Project folder, and everything lives under that. (like when you go to http://example.com/, your web daemon is configured to look in your 'Project' folder?)

so you should be able to do:

```
document.getElementById("image").src = "/img/1.png";
```

the first slash says "go to my root folder, whatever that is on the web server", and then the rest is just the remaining path.